# Install Ubuntu automatically on a USB stick from a mac

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb

I have one of the latest Macbook (2017, Touchbar) and I am trying to install Ubuntu on it. VirtualBox being too slow, I decided to dual boot it but I don't have a lot of storage so I finally bought a 64GB Usb Stick to install Ubuntu on it.

First step, I followed tutorials to download the .iso, convert it with hdiutil, format my usb key to be bootable and put the image file on the usb key. Then I restart my mac and by pressing the option key and booting on the usb, I get to a menu where I can choose between Install ubuntu and Try ubuntu.

I have tried both but it doesn't work. In both cases, I first have to choose a language, then if I want to connect to wifi and then if I want to install updates automatically and install third-party softwares. I answered no to the last three items and moved to the next step.

I then have to "choose an installation type" ie partition my usb key. In most of the tutorials I found, people could choose to partition automatically or even to install ubuntu automatically without this step, but I didn't have such options.

So I clicked "create a new partition table" then created a boot partition of 250MB (EFI), a root / of 15GB (ext4), a swap of 4GB and a /home with the remaining space (ext4). I have tried several others partitioning with stuff I found online but each time, when I click Install, it tells me it failed to create a partition or a file system and I can't continue the installation (next step would be to choose my city for the time GMT).

Any idea on what I did wrong or on how I could get the partitioning step done automatically? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to install to the same USB stick you're booting from? Can't be done.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, I thought it would create some live USB. But what are my options? When I select Install Ubuntu, it doesn't offer me to install it alongside my current OS. Also, in the partitioning menu, I can only select my usb key and not the harddrive of my mac, if that makes sense.

Comment: I don't know Macs. They may need additional or different steps and/or different bootloaders like rEFInd but generally if you can boot a live session you should be able to install in any unallocated space. So, for a dual boot you'd usually shrink partitions from inside the already running OS, then the Ubuntu installer should be able to detect it and offer the install alongside option. Or just use "something else" and manually create the additional partitions. You can also install in *another* external USB HDD or stick, not the same one you're running the live session (and the installer) from.